# issue using 2 sections inside <footer> element

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have 2 sections inside my `<footer>` element.

My 1st section I want to have some columns with content. (its owrking fine)

My 2nd section I want to have below the 1st section and I want to have a black background with a paragraph aligned at left.

I think Im doing everything ok but its not working correctly.

Do you see what can be wrong in my code?

**Im having this**:

[image]

**But Im trying this:**

[image]

**My jsfiddle** with issue Im having:

http://jsfiddle.net/ra3zc/1/

**My html:**

```
<footer id="footer-container">
    <section id="footer">
         <div id="col" >
            <h1>Title of my column 1</h1>
            <p>Content of col 1</p>
        </div>
         <div id="col" >
            <h1>Title of my column 2</h1>
            <p>Content of col 2</p>
        </div> 
         <div id="col" >
            <h1>Title of my column 3</h1>
            <p>Content of col 3</p>
        </div> 
    </section>
  <section id="footer2">
        <p>&copy; I want copyright float at left in section 2</p>
    </section>
  </footer>
```

**My css:**

```
#footer-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left; 
    background:gray;
} 

#footer
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#col
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px; 
    margin:10px 53px 10px 0;
    width:200px;
}

#col h1
{
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
}

#col p
{

    color:#ccc; 
    font-size:14px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}  


#footer
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:#000;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your floats weren't clearing.

All you need to know about floats: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ra3zc/2/

```
#footer-container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:gray;
}
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#col {
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin:10px 53px 10px 0;
    width:200px;
}
#col h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#col p {
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#footer2 {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:#000;
}
#footer2 p {
    padding: 2em 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works fine! And the link you gave me is very good for me, because sometimes I still get confused with floats and overflows!

Answer (score 1):

```
<footer id="footer-container">
<section id="footer">
     <div id="col" >
        <h1>Title of my column 1</h1>
        <p>Content of col 1</p>
    </div>
     <div id="col" >
        <h1>Title of my column 2</h1>
        <p>Content of col 2</p>
    </div> 
     <div id="col" >
        <h1>Title of my column 3</h1>
        <p>Content of col 3</p>
    </div> 
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
  <section id="footer2">
    <p>&copy; I want copyright float at left in section 2</p>
</section>
</footer>
```

plus:

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

have a look the additional div between the sections

Comment: You can fix the float/clearing issue without adding extra unnecessary markup.

Comment: but it took me 0.5 secs to fix it and such a clearing div is kind of swiss army knife for those issues. Of course does better solutions exist, but that's a fast one and working correctly too.